# Is there a way that i can call thead and tdata in intro.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, intro.js

I have an HTML of table that has Thead and Tdata, where should i put the data-intro and data-step in order for the two of them to be focused at the same time.. sorry newbie here kindly help me thanks in advance..

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>TITLE</th>
        <th>AUTHOR</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
          SAMPLE TITLE
       </td>

        <td>
          SAMPLE AUTHOR
       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In latest version of IntroJS you can introduce a `tr` element to the introduction.

```
<table>
  <thead >
      <tr data-step="1" data-intro="This is thead">
        <th>TITLE</th>
        <th>AUTHOR</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr data-step="2" data-intro="tbody">
       <td>
          SAMPLE TITLE
       </td>

        <td>
          SAMPLE AUTHOR
       </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MUKn9/1/

Comment: Thank you for the answer afshin :) but is there a way that they will be focused at the same time? because at your example they were on different steps... i would like to make them on 1 step only... Thank you.

Comment: @user3770359 So you should highlight the whole `table` instead.